# stop executing code after new form is loaded

Tags: c#

Some method call this method which has this code:

```
Form frm = new Form();
frm.Show();
```

but i do not want to execute first method anymore after form is loaded. How can i prevent and stop loading code in forst form

Comment: Why can't the calling code just return? It's not really clear what you're asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very unclear, I'm guessing that you want to make sure that only *one* instance of a form can be created.  You do so by keeping track of the life of the instance.  Like this:

```
    private Form2 instance;

    private void showForm2() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Form2();
            instance.FormClosed += delegate { instance = null; };
            instance.Show();
        }
        else {
            instance.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            instance.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** question is very unclear so I give an answer based on my understanding of it...

to block execution after a form has been created, until such form is closed, try to use `ShowDialog()`

```
using(var frm = new Form1())
{
  frm.ShowDialog();

  // here your code is not executed until frm is closed...
  //...
  //...
}
```

Please pay attention that you do not want to create an object of type `Form` as that is the default base class and will not contain your controls...